# Global variables & the reader monad

Tags: haskell

I have a **module** where a global environment (defining certain constraints such as neighbor IP addresses, etc.) is created and initialized by calling an initializing function. A number of subsequent functions should use these constraints when they are called.

Whilst in principle I understand what the reader monad does I am not quite sure how I can apply this to my problem, esp.

- How it can be used to initialize an environment that is defined by the user and passed as data/arguments to the initializing function. I mean, the reader monad has to get the actual values that make up the global immutable environment from somewhere. I would like that the values are read from an initializing function call like `myinitial :: arg1 -> arg1 -> IOString` where subsequently `arg1` and `arg2` become global immutable data accessible to subsequent functions via the reader monad(?)
- How I can use these environment values as function arguments e.g. `recvFrom s arg1` where `arg1` is global immutable data from my environment. Or `if arg2 > arg1 then ... else ...`

I could make a configuration file of course, but I feel that a configuration file will take away to much flexibility.

[Edit] I understand about ask, but shouldn't there be additional "pointfree-like" ways so that the global/environment immutable can be omitted if the function signature has been defined right? How would I i.e. need to refactor my if-then-else to apply [this](http://lambdaman.blogspot.nl/2007/10/monadreader.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example that may clear things up. First you need to import the Reader module:

```
import Control.Monad.Reader
```

Now let's define some data structure (that we're going to use to hold a name and an age)

```
data Config = Config { name :: String, age :: Int }
```

Now define a function that works in the Reader monad (it's type is `Reader Config (String, Int)` but we don't need to specify that - it can be inferred). All this function does is ask for the environment (of type `Config`) and then extracts the fields and does something with them.

```
example = do
    c <- ask
    return ("Hello " ++ name c, 2 * age c)
```

Now we put it all together into a program. The first four lines after the do block allow the user to enter their name and age. Then we build a `Config` structure using the user's inputs (we have to use `read` to convert the variable `_age`, which is a `String`, into an `Int` so that we can feed it to the `Config` constructor) and execute `example` with this environment, using the `runReader` function. Finally, we use the result of this computation to generate some output.

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Enter your name:"
    _name <- getLine
    putStrLn "Enter your age:"
    _age <- getLine
    let config = Config _name (read _age)
    let result = runReader example config
    putStrLn $ fst result
    putStrLn $ "Twice your age is: " ++ show (snd result)
```

Comment: Works partially, as mentioned in the question I have a **module** that has a number of functions; amongst them is one initializing function that creates the environment. Functions from the module that are called later should use the environment. Is that possible with the reader monad at all?

Comment: But how should this work? In your/my example the initializer function would say something like `let config = Config blabla` and a subsequent function would need to do `let result = runReader example config`; - however the subsequent function does not know `config`.

Comment: Check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/2924160) which contains a simple example. In module 1, we define a function that initializes a global environment, and some functions that depend on the global environment. Module 2 just contains a main function that initializes the environment, and calls the functions that depend on it using `runReader` (**Edit:** apologies, I deleted the original comment that you replied to and replaced it with this one.)

Comment: This doesn't help me. In that example, one could just call the two functions directly with the value from the configuration, there's no need for Reader. What I'm trying to understand is how to do this where one function calls another which calls another and they ALL have access to that "global" configuration.

Comment: I replied to your comment on the gist - https://gist.github.com/chris-taylor/2924160

Answer (score 5):

Most of your questions can be answered by inspecting the types and documentation for the [ask](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/2.1.1/doc/html/Control-Monad-Reader.html#v%3aask) and [runReader](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/2.1.1/doc/html/Control-Monad-Reader.html#v%3arunReader) functions.

First, the `ask`:

```
ask :: Reader m r => m r
```

This returns the underlying read-only data wrapped in the monad. Cool, so that's how you will get to the state when you want to use it with other functions, in your example above:

```
do x <- ask
   recvFrom s x
```

(depending on the type of `recvFrom`, of course)

Next is the `runReader`, this is how you give it that initial data you were talking about. It basically just runs the `Reader` computation using the data it's given:

```
runReader :: Reader r a -> r -> a
```

which means: run the computation (the first argument) with the read-only data of type `r` (the second argument). It finally will return the result type of the 1st argument, `a`. In your case, this may look like:

```
result = runReader computationUsingArg1Arg2 (arg1, arg2)
```

Then inside `computationUsingArg1Arg2` you can read `arg1` and `arg2` via `ask`.

Comment: Thanks, I still don't understand how to apply the 'runReader' to my example bullet one of my question.

Comment: I've expanded the answer a little, let me know if there's still something that's not clear.

Comment: I know it's a year later but to me this does not answer the question. The problem is not just that there's compuationUsingArg1Arg2, but that computationUsingArg1Arg2 might want to be able to call OTHER functions that also need access to the "global" information. Otherwise you could just pass the parameters directly and not need the reader. So how are all those other functions defined and invoked?